# How to set `setReorderingAllowed` when using Navigation Architechture?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, navigation-architecture

When postponing a fragment's enter transition when using Navigation Architecture the "home" fragment in the graph is visible for a microsecond. After googling a bit, the docs tell me to set `setReorderingAllowed(true)` on the fragmentManager to optimize this flow. However, the docs do not use the Navigation Architecture Component.

Will `setReorderingAllowed(true)` and how can I achieve it when using Navigation Architecture Component?

Comment: You can set some properties on NavHostFragment's childFragmentManager. Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks, but noo, I don't find the setReorderingAllowed method there or in any of its properties.

Comment: Maybe some kind of hack [like this](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/495#issuecomment-488364003) should help. No other ideas.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, one of the other comments in that thread helped me! I already had the `postponeEnterTransition` and `startPosponedEnterTransition` calls there, but calling them on the parent fragment fixed my issue! Ref this comment: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/495#issuecomment-530279938 
Again, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`setReorderingAllowed(true)` is set automatically when using `naivate()`. See `FragmentNavigator` implementation:

```
    public NavDestination navigate(@NonNull Destination destination, @Nullable Bundle args,
            @Nullable NavOptions navOptions, @Nullable Navigator.Extras navigatorExtras) {

        // OTHER CODE
        // OTHER CODE

        ft.setReorderingAllowed(true);
        ft.commit();
        // The commit succeeded, update our view of the world
        if (isAdded) {
            mBackStack.add(destId);
            return destination;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```